# My Python Equation Solver Can't Solve for Fractions

Tags: python, loops, integer, equation

Ok, so I made a small equation solver that solves for x. It works great for integer values, but whenever I try to solve for fractions it goes into an endless loop. Here is my code:

```
print "Make the variable in your equation stand for x"
print
startingLimit=int(raw_input("What is the lowest estimate that your variable could possibly be?"))
print
wholeNumber=raw_input("Do you know if your variable will be a whole number or a fraction? Answer: yes/no")
if (wholeNumber== "yes"):
    print
    fraction= raw_input("Is it a decimal/fraction? Answer:yes/no")
    if (fraction=="yes"):
        print
        print "This program will only calculate up to the 2nd place to the right of the decimal"
        xfinder=float(0.01)
    else:
        xfinder=int(1)
else:
    xfinder=float(0.01)


leftEquation=raw_input("Enter your left side of the equation:")
print
rightEquation=raw_input("Enter the right side of the equation:")
print
amountSolutions=100

print

#solving

a=0
indivisualCount=0
count=0
x=float(startingLimit)
while (count!=amountSolutions):
    ifstuffleft=eval(leftEquation)
    ifstuffright=eval(rightEquation)
    if (ifstuffleft!=ifstuffright):
        x=float(x+xfinder)
        print x
    else:
        a=(a+1)
        count=count+1
        print "Solution",a,"=",x
        print
        x=float(x+xfinder)
```

Answer (score 5):

`if (ifstuffleft!=ifstuffright):` should become

`if abs(ifstuffleft - ifstuffright) < tolerance:`

Where `tolerance` is the error you're willing to accept

Comment: This highlights that the OP needs to read about how floating point values are stored on a computer.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart, don't take offence, but that doesn't look like a costructive response to the OP. at least give him a link to the python manual section: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint. For user1624992, the problem is how the floating point are treated inside the computer, representation that make the equality test a risky operation that almost never return True, and this is why you program is stuck in an endless loop